# How to call and process codebehind function inside javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

at View of My project, I got a string variable with ajax from controller and  i want to process this string with codebehind function named 'MakeSeoUrl' then put this processed value inside the variable named 'titleURL'.

I thought that it could be used as '@MVCHelper.RouteHelper.MakeSeoUrl(response.BlogEntries[i].Title);' but it is wrong and it says 'response' does not exist. what should i do? how inside javascipt codebehind function is used.

AT VIEW

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/Map/GetBlogEntries",
                    type: "post",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: placeMarker,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.Success) {                                
                            var titleURL;
                            for(var i = 0; i < response.BlogEntries.length ; i ++){
                                titleURL =@MVCHelper.RouteHelper.MakeSeoUrl(response.BlogEntries[i].Title);
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                          //.....
                        }
                    },                        
                    error: function (xhr, status) {                            
                        //......
                    }
                });
```

AT CONTROLLER

```
public JsonResult GetBlogEntries(MarkerOfPlace placeMarker)
    {
        try
        {
            List<BlogEntry> blogEntries = _blogEntryRepo.GetAll(x => x.IsActive.Value && x.PlaceMarkerID == placeMarker.Id).ToList();                

            return Json(new { Success = true, BlogEntries = blogEntries});
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false, Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript cannot call server-side method directly; you need to use Ajax.

Easiest way to fix the issue is to return anonymous type with `SeoUrl` along with BlogEntry's other properties.

```
public JsonResult GetBlogEntries(MarkerOfPlace placeMarker)
{
    try
    {
        var blogEntries = _blogEntryRepo
            .GetAll(x => x.IsActive.Value && x.PlaceMarkerID == placeMarker.Id)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ... Map BlogEntry's other properties here
                Title = x.Title,
                SeoUrl = MVCHelper.RouteHelper.MakeSeoUrl(x.Title)
            })
            .ToList();

        return Json(new { Success = true, BlogEntries = blogEntries });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false, Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a server-side method in javascript (client-side).

What you should do instead, is use a viewmodel and return an already formatted response from your API action result:

```
public class BlogEntryViewModel 
{
    // any other properties you need
    public string TitleUrl { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult GetBlogEntries(MarkerOfPlace placeMarker)
{
    try
    {
        var blogEntries = _blogEntryRepo.GetAll(x => x.IsActive.Value && x.PlaceMarkerID == placeMarker.Id)
        .Select(e => new BlogEntryViewModel {
            TitleUrl = MVCHelper.RouteHelper.MakeSeoUrl(e.Title),
            // other properties here
        })
        .ToList();                

        return Json(new { Success = true, BlogEntries = blogEntries});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Success = false, Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```